# :: React Native :: Get data from another db table not working

Tags: react-native

I have a React native project

I want to display manufacture's name (brand name) above the product name like below

```
<View style={styles.infromationView}>
  <Text>{data.manufacturers.name}</Text>
  <Text>{data.product_description.name}</Text>
</View>
```

[image]

While adding the name, I am getting error as **Cannot read property 'name' of undefined** while getting the **manufacturer / brand** name table, But I am able to get the same product name from **product_description** table

[image]
[image]

> **Please check below for db structure...**

[image]

> **Above table data is working as expected..**

> **But, when I try to get the data from this table, I am getting error**

[image]

Comment: You may confirm your `data` object has `manufacturers` key by `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` before return.

Comment: You can confirm that the manufacturers' variable inside the data object is also an object or an array. You can try logging the data inside some useEffect. Also, a suggestion you are rendering TEXT element without putting any validator, like 
data && data.manufacturers && data.manufacturers.name ? data.manufacturers.name : "".
You can try a validator like this.

Comment: If you can provide any test API link to understand your response structure or the response structure itself, then probably people can provide better help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Text>{data?.manufacturers?.name}</Text>
```

for more info: [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

In this, you might be missing values, that's why it's showing error!

Comment: it is not working :(

Comment: have tried logging the data?.manufacturers

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this error by

```
<Text>{data?.manufacturers?.name || ''}</Text>
```

But i think here is the issue is with your API response. I think API response data has no property name "manufacturers".

Please confirm it by `console.log({data})`.